# Getting 404 from microservices in gateway front

Tags: jhipster

I've created a microservices architecture following jhipster instructions. I have a gateway, the registry and a simple microservice. After that i've called the entity sub-generator in the gateway to generate the front-end code for the microservice.
After doing that, I can propertly create/list/update the microservice resources from the Administration-API section in the gateway, but in the 'Entities' section (via front-end) i'm getting a 404 in all the microservices requests.
The 3 apps are running in dev profile, and the jwt secret token is the same for all of them:  my-secret-token-to-change-in-production. I have not touched the config ymls.

¿What could be the problem? 404 is not a security problem ¿Isn't it? ¿Maybe the problem is the proxy? I'm behind a proxy.

I follow the Julien Dubois video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOO-8cAKDu8 and he just re-generate the entity in the gateway to access the front-end via 'Entities' menu (minute 33 aprox).

Thank you!

Gateway generator options:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.6.1",
    "baseName": "testgw",
    "packageName": "com.test.app",
    "packageFolder": "com/test/app",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "jwtSecretKey": "92bc8dd1e1cb0aacacfebe994abfb472862c512d",
    "useSass": true,
    "applicationType": "gateway",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber",
      "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "es",
    "languages": [
      "es",
      "en"
    ]
  }
}
```

Microservice generator options:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.6.1",
    "baseName": "patient",
    "packageName": "com.test.app",
    "packageFolder": "com/test/app",
    "serverPort": "8081",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "jwtSecretKey": "f9e757eb9259f0cfd8886bb08beda392463a4391",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "applicationType": "microservice",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "skipClient": true,
    "skipUserManagement": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "es",
    "languages": [
      "es",
      "en"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Compare the requests in browser console log in both cases (admin or entities menues)

Comment: Hi @GaëlMarziou The only difference is the cacheBuster param: 404 request: http://127.0.0.1:8080/patient/api/patients?cacheBuster=1472457427378&page=0&size=20&sort=id,asc while 200 request: http://127.0.0.1:8080/patient/api/patients?page=0&size=20&sort=id%2Casc

Comment: to analyze your problem, try to curl that uri on your own...furthermore, check your registry whether your patient service successfully registered with euraka...try to address your service direclty, not over gateway

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Finally I found the problem: I had different names 1: in my jdl file for generating the entities I had: "microservice * with **patients**" while 2: the name of the microservice proyect was  **patient**

Comment: Checking correctness of microservice project name in entity.json file in .jhipster folder solved the problem. Thanks to @arturo.galan .